# Function result in an array of own structure

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, function, structure

In the Gen class file I have got this structure:

```html
    Public Structure StructElements
        Public ID As Integer
        Public Name As String
    End Structure
```

An then this function:

```html
 Public Function FillElements(_param As String, count As Integer) As StructElements
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
        Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader

        myConn.ConnectionString = sc.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sidConnectionString").ConnectionString
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & _param

        Select Case _param
            Case = "Scopes"
                Dim Scope(count) As StructElements
                myConn.Open()
                myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
                While myReader.Read
                    Scope(i).ID = myReader.Item(0)
                    Scope(i).Name = myReader.Item(1).ToString
                    i += 1
                End While
                myReader.Close()
                myCmd.Dispose()
                myConn.Close()
                myConn.Dispose()
                Return Scope
        ...
        End Function
```

Then in the edit.aspx codebehind I have:

```html
Public Class edit
    ...
    Public istGen = New Gen()
    ...
    Public iScopes As Integer
    Public Scope(iScopes) As StructElements
    ...
    
    Private Sub edit_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
      ...
      iScopes = istGen.CountElements("Scopes") - 1
      ReDim Scope(iScopes)
      Scope = istGen.FillElements("Scopes", iScopes)
      ...
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the error I get:
**Value of type 'Gen.StructElements()' cannot be converted to 'Gen.StructElements'.**

I have figured out the problem is with the "Return Scope" of the FillElements function since it's expecting as an output a StructElements and not an array of StructElements (that's what the Scope variable is). How should I change my code in order for the function output to be an array of StructElements?

I have tried to look for an answer on the web but didn't find much. Someone was suggesting to use lists instead of arrays, but that would request to heavily refurbish my code and project, so if there is an easy way to do it I would strongly prefer it.

Thanks in advance for your support.
Regards.

Comment: Look at the return type of your method. If you want to return an array, why is that return type not an array? Look at the error message. It's telling you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: That's precisely what I said, I know where the problem is, I just don't know how to change the code. I tried a few things as declaring the function "as Array" instead of StructElements but it didn't work. If you know how to fix it can you please simply point it out? Many thanks.

Comment: *"If you know how to fix it can you please simply point it out?"* You need to learn to think like a developer. You're ignoring what's right in front of you. Look at the error message. It's telling that you have a `StructElements` array and that cannot be converted to a `StructElements`. The reason it's trying to do that conversion is because that's' what you specified the return type as. The error message is telling you what you should have declared the return type as so declare it as that type.

Comment: There was more to it, but I think I get it now.
I had already tried to declare the return type "as StructElements ()"  before to write this post but I was still getting an error, and even though it was a different one, I thought it was similar.

Comment: "System.InvalidCastException: '[A]StructElements[] cannot be cast to [B]StructElements[]" (same structure declared in different classes). After a bit of research I have understood that somehow I can't get a reference of a structure through an instance of a class (istGen) but I have to do it through the class itself (Gen), so in the edit page codebehind I have also changed the Scope variable declaration as follow: "Public Scope(iScopes) As Gen.StructElements", deleted the structure from the edit class and now it works.

Comment: You should not be declaring structures inside classes in the first place. A structure is a first-class type and they should be declared in their own dedicated code file named after the type, just like classes. I generally use the *Add -> New Class* option and then just change the `Class` keyword to `Structure` in the code.